# How to make Github Actions workflow that is triggered by a pr comment to be reported in the pr checks

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a called workflow that deploys the app to Heroku. It is triggered by a pr comment.

```
name: Preview App Deployment
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  call-heroku-preview-app:
    name: Deploy to Heroku
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.comment.body, '/deploy') }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/heroku-preview-app.yml
```

However, it doesn't show up in the pr checks as it does for jobs that are triggered by

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [synchronize, opened, reopened, ready_for_review]
    branches-ignore: [master, production]
```

which hurts visibility.  Also, I'm planning to add another workflow triggered by a comment that runs unit and e2e tests. If the result won't be included in the Github checks it will be a problem.

So is it really impossible to include them there or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR Checks are attached to a commit, but when you're running a workflow on `issue_comment` what would the context be? Intuitively, comment in a PR is not a thing related to a commit.

In fact, when looking at `${{ github.sha }}` inside a workflow triggered by `issue_comment`, the SHA is actually that of the default branch.

---

You could manually add a check using the [Check Runs API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs#create-a-check-run).

**However**, when triggering this on `issue_comment`, you're going to have to replace the value `github.sha` with your own logic to identify the tip of the branch associated with the PR for which the comment was made.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- run: echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | gh auth login --with-token
- run: echo '{"name":"Test Check","head_sha":"${{ github.sha }}"}' | gh api /repos/{owner}/{repo}/check-runs --input -
```

---

Is there are reason you're only deploying when a comment is made? Why not deploy on every push? As you mentioned end-to-end tests as well, this would be another type of thing that is usually run automatically rather than when a person adds a comment.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. I have a lot of stuff going on in pr checks right now and want to optimise billable time in GitHub Actions so decided to experiment with running checks on a comment

Comment: How about using a label `ready-for-testing`? You could then still use `on: push`, but add an `if: ...pr has label` to actually run the tests. Or instead of a label even search through comments :)

Comment: Yeah, that might work. I wonder if the tests/deploy would be triggered when the label is set. I guess the workflow would be - set the label, push a commit, which seems a bit too much

Comment: Using PR labels worked for me. Thanks! I'll accept the answer in case someone still wants to use `issue_comment`

Comment: "Why not deploy on every push?" I don't want to start a discussion here, but speaking for myself, I just want to avoid unnecessary server workload for every random end-of-day commit. Green IT and all that. :)